# May one eat outside of the sukkah during chol hamoed if there isn't a sukkah nearby where one works?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, eating, employment, sukkah

If someone is at work during chol hamoed and is not nearby a sukkah may he eat outside of the sukkah and if so is there any limitation to what that includes?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31316/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio Dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA not sure -- the other is more specific, so an answer to that wouldn't necessarily answer this.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem from the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (135:22) that they would need to eat in the Sukka.

> הַיוֹשְׁבִים בַּחֲנוּת, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהֵם דָּרִים חוּץ לָעִיר וְהַחֲנוּת הִיא בָּעִיר וּרְגִילִין כָּל הַשָׁנָה בְּרֹב פְּעָמִים לֶאֱכוֹל שָׁם בַּיּוֹם, מִכָּל מָקוֹם בַּסֻּכּוֹת חַיָבִים לֶאֱכוֹל בַּסֻּכָּה.‏

Obviously, this is only if they want to eat bread, or they sit down to a meal - even it it only consists of meat or fruit.

Snacking (on anything but bread) is allowed outside of a Sukka. (ibid:7)

> בִּשְׁאָר הַלֵּילוֹת וְכֵן בְּכָל הַיָמִים, אֵין חִיוּב לֶאֱכֹל בַּסֻּכָּה, אֶלָּא שֶׁאִם הוּא רוֹצֶה לֶאֱכֹל אֲכִילַת קֶבַע אוֹ לִישֹׁן, צָרִיךְ לֶאֱכֹל אוֹ לִישֹׁן בַּסֻּכָּה. וּמַהִי אֲכִילַת קֶבַע. פַּת יוֹתֵר מִכַּבֵּיצָה, אֲפִלּוּ לֹא קָבַע עָלֶיהָ, וַאֲפִלּוּ הִיא פַּת כִּסְנִין. וְכֵן תַּבְשִׁיל הֶעָשׂוּי מֵחֲמֵשֶׁת מִנֵי דָגָן יוֹתֵר מִכַּבֵּיצָה וְקָבַע עָלָיו, חַיָב בַּסֻּכָּה וּלְבָרֵךְ עָלָיו לֵישֵׁב בַּסֻּכָּה. אֲבָל פֵּרוֹת, אֲפִלּוּ אָכַל הַרְבֵּה וְקָבַע עֲלֵיהֶם, מֻתָּר לֶאֱכוֹל חוּץ לַסֻּכָּה. וְכֵן יַיִן אוֹ שְׁאָר מַשְׁקִין אוֹ בָשָׂר וּגְבִינָה, מֻתָּר לֶאֱכוֹל וְלִשְׁתּוֹת חוּץ לַסֻּכָּה. וְדַוְקָא כְּשֶׁלֹּא קָבַע עֲלֵיהֶם. אֲבָל אִם רוֹצֶה לִשְׁתּוֹת יַיִן אוֹ שְׁאָר מַשְׁקִים בְּדֶרֶךְ קֶבַע, **אוֹ שֶׁרוֹצֶה לֶאֱכֹל בָּשָׂר אוֹ גְבִינָה דֶּרֶךְ קֶבַע, צָרִיךְ סֻכָּה**, וְלֹא יְבָרֵךְ עֲלֵיהֶם לֵישֵׁב בַּסֻּכָּה. וְטוֹב שֶׁיֹאכַל קֹדֶם, פַּת, כְּדֵי שֶׁיְבָרֵךְ. וְכָל זֹאת, מִדִּינָא. אֲבָל מִי שֶׁמַּחְמִיר עַל עַצְמוֹ שֶׁאֲפִלוּ מַיִם אֵינוֹ שׁוֹתֶה חוּץ לַסֻּכָּה, הֲרֵי זֶה מְשֻׁבָּח.‏

Comment: Why is he not a Holchei Derachim?

Comment: @DoubleAA that term seems not to apply to somebody who sits in a shop all day, even if he needs to travel a while to get there. After all, he can build a sukka as he's not running all over the place all the time.

Comment: @danny Schoemann but what if the guy at work cant build a sukkah near where he works?

Comment: @Orion - then he'll have to eat only those things that don't require a Sukkah, I guess. (Similarly: If nobody sells Matza nearby, what would you suggest he do on Pesach? )

Comment: @danny no I meant if the difference between traveling and sitting in a shop unable to to go to a sukkah is that the guy in the shop can build a sukkah then what about if he can't build a sukkah anywhere? Is he then considered like traveling?