# Making a sukkah your house

Tags: halacha-theory, sukkah, sukkot

They say your sukkah should become like your house for all of Sukkot, meaning you eat there, sleep there, and just spend most of your time there. However normally, one doesn’t always let’s say eat in there house…people go out to eat all the time. If you go out to eat on sukkot you’re still obligated to eat in a sukkah, why? That’s just one example but in short, there’s plenty of stuff we don’t always do in our homes normally so why are we obligated to strictly do them in the sukkah?

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31316

Comment: The premise is not true. Travelers are exempt from eating in sukkah while traveling.

Comment: You’re not traveling anywhere though. Let’s say you walk down the block to a restaurant, why should you have to eat in a sukkah if this is something you usually do during the year outside of your house

Comment: @CuriousYid your question is on a BBQ in a park not a restaurant. A restaurant is just another house that you go to. Eating in a park as a form of leisure is probably not something chazal ever imagined.